# All full screen software go to desktop at launch

Tags: windows-7, fullscreen, optimus

All the applications that run at full screen launch, show a black screen and then return to the desktop. I've already cecked and nothing is popping up and showing notifications or other windows. I've also checked the keyboard for stuck keys. The problem happens on a Acer E1-570G with Windows 7 and the Nvidia optimus system, can this be the source of the problem?
I can get programs to stay open if I keep bashing keyboard and mouse randomly when the program loads, that is really strange.

Comment: Is there any log in Event Viewer at the time it happens ? If there is it may help in finding the cause.

Comment: It seems that nothing happened in the Event viewer but I could be wrong since I don't know what to look for. I just tried with and without desktop composition(compatibility mode) and updated the nvidia and the intel drivers, but nothing.

Comment: You would need to look under Windows Logs >> Application

Comment: Nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is a graphics driver problem. reinstall driver (using driver uninstaller). if the problem didn't resolve, contact ASUS support.

Comment: My laptop is Acer, not Asus, the support is not going to help me over a certain point since the comupter came with Win8 wich I have removed and installed Windows 7 and Kubuntu in dual boot. I'll have to unistall the Nvidia or the Intel driver? My laptop has the Nivida optimus system.

Comment: @Fabiusp98 - What exactly are you asking?  This problem sounds like a display driver problem.  Do you have OEM display drivers that specifically highlight Windows 7 support?

Comment: No, I only installed the drivers that drivereasy told me to install

Answer (score 0):

Try to force Vertical Sync.

> nVidia Control Panel > Advanced > Manage 3D Settings > Global
>   settings, scroll down to the bottom > Vertical Sync > Select Force On

Or use [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm) for this.

Comment: And only for me can you try run game without "explorer.exe". Copy game path, kill "explorer.exe" with Task Manager(ctrl+alt+del). Task Manager->File->New Task->paste game path->enter.